Hi. Problem with cursor inisialization. Problem on row 23 but data exists (App inspection ok). Searching in this site but nothing issue for me
Method to get data :
public ArrayList<DataModel> getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_DATA, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String Name = cursor.getString(1)
                ...
                int number15 = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(23));
                int number16 = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(24));

                DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(id, Name,...      ...number1,number2);
                arrayList.add(DataModel);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

Display Data :
private void showDatas() {
        arrayList = datasDb.getdataData();
        adapter = new DatasListAdapter (this, arrayList);
        lvDatasList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

App works if :
int number15 = 0;
int number16 = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(24));
An idee ?
Tks

DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(id, Name,...      ...number15,number16);

I recreate my app line per line and work fine till, this time, row 20 over 21. Again the penultimate.

Solved : mistake with my n° of column index. Sorry.
